# Why can't separate the function for xmlHttp.onreadystatechange?

Tags: javascript, ajax, onreadystatechange

The below js file `test`.js` works fine in my html.

```
function sendData()
{
    var formData = new FormData( document.querySelector("form") );
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("post", "test.php",true); 
    xmlHttp.send(formData); 
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange =  function(){
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){ 
        alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
}
}

ob = document.getElementById("submit"); 
ob.addEventListener("click",sendData);
```

Now i want to separate them

```
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){ 
        alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
```

in a single function.

I rewrite the test1.js as test2.js.

```
var xmlHttp;
function ready(){        
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200){ 
        alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }
}

function sendData()
{
    var formData = new FormData( document.querySelector("form") );
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("post", "test.php",true); 
    xmlHttp.send(formData); 
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange =  ready;
}

ob = document.getElementById("submit"); 
ob.addEventListener("click",sendData);
```

The `test2.js` encounter error info:

```
test2.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'readyState' of undefined
    at XMLHttpRequest.ready (test2.js:4)
```

Another issue :what is the right order for the following statements?
I have seen some material write them as below :

```
    xmlHttp.open("post", "test.php",true); 
    xmlHttp.send(formData); 
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange =  function(){  }
```

Other material also seen:

```
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange =  function(){  }
    xmlHttp.open("post", "test.php",true); 
    xmlHttp.send(formData);
```

And other order in webpage  [xmlHttp statements order](https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-use-the-callback-function-ajax.cfm)

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "Demo", true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=myCallBack;
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.send("FirstName=Nat&LastName=Dunn");
```

Comment: Just pass xmlHttp as a parameter...

Comment: I have defined xmlHttp as a global function,no need to pass xmlHttp as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `sendData` you have:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Your only mistake is including the `var` here - just do this instead:

```
xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

The reason this matters is that the `var` is declaring a new local variable of the same name, which is then getting assigned to - so `ready` doesn't get access to it. It accesses the global `xmlHttp` variable, which is never assigned to. By removing the `var` as shown above, you ensure that the global variable is assigned to - and this should work. (Although of course it's not best practice to use globals.)

Comment: Another issue :what is the right order for the following statements?